# Keyboard shortcut to run maven goals in Intellij IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to run a maven goal using keyboard shortcut in Intellij IDEA?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Settings | Keymap | Maven Goals** (or right click on the Maven goal in the IDEA **Maven Projects** panel and select **Assign Shortcut...**)

Comment: I was looking for something like: 1. press shortcut, then 2. type in the desired maven goal. Does something like that exist?

Comment: If you create IDEA Run/Debug configuration for your Maven goal, then you can run it like described at http://blogs.jetbrains.com/idea/2009/10/invoking-rundebug-actions-in-intellij-idea-9/.

Answer (score 4):

You can associate a `Maven` goal with a keyboard shortcut and execute commonly-used goals with a single key-stroke. In a Maven project, its goals appear under the Maven goals node in the 
[`Keymap`](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/keymap.html) dialog.

To associate a keyboard shortcut with a Maven goal :

1. In the [`Maven Projects tool window`](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/maven-projects-tool-window.html), right-click the desired goal.
2. On the context menu, choose Assign Shortcut. [`Keymap`](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/keymap.html) dialog appears.
3. Configure keymap, as described in the section [`Configuring Keyboard Shortcuts`](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/configuring-ide-settings.html).

Comment: I managed to do this for one goal, e.g. mvn verify. But how do I do "mvn clean verify" with a shortcut?

Comment: 404 at http://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-ide-settings.html

Comment: @Fletch You can use the Run Configuration as Action plugin to do this. Create a Run/Debug configuration for the commands you want. Then with that plugin I mentioned, you'll be able to find hotkey options in the Keymap section for that configuration by searching for the configuration's name that you gave it.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old question but still of interest (at least for me):

So, for **IntelliJ 2017** go to **Preferences | Keymap** then assign your shortcut to *Plug-ins | Maven Integration | Execute Maven Goal*